# How can I use `path` and `lvim` to find files easily?

Tags: vim

At the moment I use :Explore to navigate to my project directory, I press 'c' to set that as the current directory. I have `set path=.,,` in my .vimrc, and then I use:

```
:lvim pattern ./**/*
```

to find patterns in files. This does work, but I have to type `./**/*` instead of just `*` or `*.rb` for example. Is there a setting for `path` that I can use to avoid having to do that?

Also, I am working in an environment where I cannot use plugins at all. (Also I would rather use vim plain-and-simple anyway) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`:lvim`, `:lgrep`, `:vim` and `:grep` don't use the `path` option: they work by default from the current directory, from the directory of the current file if you use `./` or from any arbitrary directory if you use an absolute path.

The value of `path` has no effect whatsoever: it is used for other unrelated commands.

```
:lvim pattern ./*.rb
```

would search for `pattern` in every Ruby file under the directory of the current file.

```
:lvim pattern *.rb
```

would search for `pattern` in every Ruby file under the current directory.

The *current directory* and the *directory of the current file* may or may not be the same. If both the current directory and the directory of the current file are identical, the two commands above should have the same outcome but, if they are different, those two commands could have very different outcomes so make sure you are able to tell the difference.

If you want to search in the current directory, use:

```
*.rb
```

If you want to search recursively in the current directory, use:

```
**/*.rb
```

If you want to search in the directory of the current file, use:

```
./*.rb
```

If you want to search recursively in the directory of the current file, use:

```
./**/*.rb
```

Since you have changed the current directory with netrw's `c`, it seems logical to assume that you want that directory to be the base for your search. The right command would therefore be:

```
:lvim pattern **/*.rb
```

Comment: @Kent You were right, of course, my answer was stupid. :) I deleted it and vote this up for the greater good!